# How to solve this following sum using differentiation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

So the question is to find sum of following series upto infinite terms
The series is as following $$\frac{1.3}{2} + \frac{3.5}{2^2} + \frac{5.7}{2^3}........upto\;infinite\;terms  $$

I tried it by solving using differentiation
First of all
$T_n =\frac{(2n-1)(2n+1)}{2^n}$
So
I started with
$$\sum_{n=0}^∞ x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}(infinite\;gp\; so\; |x|<1)$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^∞nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}(differentiation\;1)$$
$$\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^∞ nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{x×({1-x})^{2}}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^∞ nx^{n-2}=\frac{1}{x×({1-x})^{2}}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^∞ n(n-2)x^{n-3}=\frac{(3x-1)}{x^2×({1-x})^{3}}(differentiation \;2nd)$$
$Now \;put \;n=2n+1 \;and \;X=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{2(2n-1)(2n+1)}{2^n}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{(3\frac{1}{\sqrt2}-1)}{(\frac{1}{\sqrt2})^2×({1-(\frac{1}{\sqrt2})})^{3}}$$

ANSWER COMES OUT TO BE 16√2+22
But actual answer is 23 , so what am I doing wrong pls correct my procedure

Comment: You can't just replace $n\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ with $2n+1\in\{3,5,7,\ldots\}$ like that. The indices for the sum would also have to be accounted for.

Comment: Where does that $|n|<0$ come from?

Comment: in your nominator you have 1.3, 3.5 , 5.7 what has it ti do with (2n+1)*(2n-1)

Comment: @Guess, look at my answer. Tell me what you think about it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Expand the summand's numerator to get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2n-1)(2n+1)}{2^n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4n^2-1}{2^n} = 4 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^n} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{2^n}$$

Answer (score 1):

For any $\,x\in(-1,1)\,$ it results that

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty(2n-1)(2n+1)x^n=\!\sum_{n=1}^\infty\big[2(n\!+\!1)-3\big]\big[2(n\!+\!2)-3\big]x^n=$

$=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\big[4(n+1)(n+2)-6(n+1)-6(n+2)+9\big]x^n=$

$=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\big[4(n+1)(n+2)-12(n+1)+3\big]x^n=$

$=4\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty(n+1)(n+2)x^n-12\sum_{n=1}^\infty(n+1)x^n+3\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=$

$=4\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty D\big[(n+2)x^{n+1}\big]-12\sum_{n=1}^\infty Dx^{n+1}+3\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=$

$=4\displaystyle D\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+2)x^{n+1}\right]-12D\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n+1}\right)+3\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=$

$=4\displaystyle D\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty Dx^{n+2}\right]-12D\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n+1}\right)+3\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=$

$=4\displaystyle D\left[D\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n+2}\right)\right]-12D\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n+1}\right)+3\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=$

$=4\displaystyle D\left[D\left(x^3\!\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\right)\right]-12D\left(x^2\!\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\right)+3x\!\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=$

$=4D\left[D\left(\dfrac{x^3}{1-x}\right)\right]-12D\left(\dfrac{x^2}{1-x}\right)+\dfrac{3x}{1-x}=$

$=4D\left[\dfrac{3x^2-2x^3}{(1-x)^2}\right]-12\!\cdot\!\dfrac{2x-x^2}{(1-x)^2}+\dfrac{3x}{1-x}=$

$=4\!\cdot\!\dfrac{6x-6x^2+2x^3}{(1-x)^3}-12\!\cdot\!\dfrac{2x-x^2}{(1-x)^2}+\dfrac{3x}{1-x}=$

$=\dfrac{3x+6x^2-x^3}{(1-x)^3}=\dfrac{x(3+6x-x^2)}{(1-x)^3}\,.$

We have proved that

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty(2n-1)(2n+1)x^n=\dfrac{x(3+6x-x^2)}{(1-x)^3}\;\,,\!\quad$ $\forall x\in(-1,1)\,.$

In particular, for $\,x=\dfrac12\,,\,$ we get that

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(2n-1)(2n+1)}{2^n}=\dfrac{\frac12\left(3+3-\frac14\right)}{\left(1-\frac12\right)^3}=23\,.$

Comment: How did you take (n+1) which you let D put out of summation as summation is function of n so the value keeps changing so how did you let it out of summation?

Comment: @Guess, if you want to understand it, read [this](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/calculus2/chapter/differentiating-and-integrating-power-series/) and [this](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~kab/311/notes4.pdf).